# HTTPS for configured site in ISPConfig returns No Data Received

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu

Currently I have ISPConfig installed. I see a problem whenever I try to access a domain with ssl(https://) it always return `No data received` even though I checked for SSL in the ISPConfig admin panel. I have already changed my ISPConfig to use the correct certificates and it works perfectly. I don't notice any logs being made in apache2 after the error and I'm using the same SSL for the domain and my ISPConfig. Any guidance would be well appreciated!

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out AT&T Uverse uses wireless STB's that carry an access point that connects to the router and to the outside world with port 443. So whenever it is connected it conflicts with anything else running on port 443.